# execute PHP code when selecting a combobox item

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a static combobox in a php web page.I want when selecting an item from this combobox (example 'item 1') the php execute a SELECT statement to get the value of a field named 'item 1' from a table X in my database.

How that can be done ?

Comment: "php web page" - probably html web page. Use AJAX request to php script that does the thing and returns a message or whatever it has to be.

Comment: This needs to be done using AJAX, you neeed to listen when the list item is click and grab the value use the $.get to pull data from the server using an givemethedate.php ( example ). Thats the way to go on this one.

Comment: You need to show your relevant code (select box and PHP code at the very minimum), and it is expected that you show some attempt at figuring this out first.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to do this. Here is a simple example:

### HTML

Just a simple select box, for the purposes of this example.

```
<select id='items'>
    <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

### JavaScript

I'm going to use jQuery here, you don't have to if you don't want to but it makes AJAX a whole lot easier.

The browser will listen for a `change` event on the select box and perform an AJAX request to the appropriate URL. When the server sends back data, the success function will be triggered. [Read more about `.ajax()` in the jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#items').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'pageWithPhpCode.php',
            data: {
                itemID: $(this).val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // do whatever here
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### PHP

Here I'm retrieving the data, [JSON encoding](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it, and sending it back to the client with the appropriate MIME type. I'm not sure how you connect to your MySQL database, but I'm using [PDO](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) here.

Keep in mind that [mysql_* functions are *deprecated*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['itemID'])) {
    $db = new PDO();
    // ... connect to your database, however you do it

    $q = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = :itemid;';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bindValue(':itemid', $_GET['itemID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $output = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```