# Running a PHP Script without redirecting or refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery

I am very new to PHP and Javascript.
Now I am running a PHP Script by using  but it redirect to another page.
the code is

```
<a name='update_status' target='_top'
href='updateRCstatus.php?rxdtime=".$time."&txid=".$txid."&balance=".$balance."&ref=".$ref."'>Update</a>
```

How do I execute this code without redirecting to another page and get a popup of success and fail alert message.

My script code is -

```
<?PHP
$rxdtime=$_GET["rxdtime"];
$txid=$_GET["txid"];
$balance=$_GET["balance"];
$ref=$_GET["ref"];
-------- SQL Query --------
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: The answer I wrote about an hour ago here may help: [execute PHP code when selecting a combobox item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348092/execute-php-code-when-selecting-a-combobox-item/18349272#18349272)

Comment: ajax is built for this sole purpose

Comment: This kind of question is better fitting not for Q&A but for reading books about the topic, reading tutorials and making a more broad use of the internet. It's just asked hundred times a day, answered maybe thenth times a day and too many duplicates on this website to have this rightly working here.

Comment: In this case Ajax will help you. Try to learn about Jquery.
Here is the API Documentation with Examples: [Jquery Ajax Examples and Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a too broad formulation of cluster-mega-duplicate material.

Comment: @hakre, I agree, but everyone has to start somewhere. In this case it does not sound like they even knew about the tech, so they would not have known what to search for.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+php+js+site:stackoverflow.com - About 357,000 results just on stackoverflow alone. That implies you need to research before asking otherwise it's only adding on top. So if you agree what is your suggestion? To add on top to destroy the Q&A character? Well, I push you back to search with so many results. And no, I don't have a problem if someone asks a question by mistake, I have no problem to leave a comment. But answering? Seriously? You wanna breed the next help vampire? Really?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating jQuery AJAX requests to a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016701/creating-jquery-ajax-requests-to-a-php-function)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to do this. Here is a simple example:

### HTML

Just a simple link, like you have in the question. However I'm going to modify the structure a bit to keep it a bit cleaner:

```
<a id='update_status' href='updateRCstatus.php' data-rxdtime='$time' data-txid='$txid'  data-balance='$balance' data-ref='$ref'>Update</a>
```

I'm assuming here that this code is a double-quoted string with interpolated variables.

### JavaScript

Since you tagged jQuery... I'll use jQuery :)

The browser will listen for a `click` event on the link and perform an AJAX request to the appropriate URL. When the server sends back data, the success function will be triggered. [Read more about `.ajax()` in the jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

As you can see, I'm using `.data()` to get the GET parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#update_status').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behaviour of following the link

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            data: {
                rxdtime: $(this).data('rxdtime'),
                txid: $(this).data('txid'),
                balance: $(this).data('balance'),
                ref: $(this).data('ref')
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                // do whatever here
                if(data === 'success') {
                    alert('Updated succeeded');
                } else {
                    alert(data); // perhaps an error message?
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### PHP

Looks like you know what you're doing here. The important thing is to output the appropriate data type.

```
<?php
$rxdtime=$_GET["rxdtime"];
$txid=$_GET["txid"];
$balance=$_GET["balance"];
$ref=$_GET["ref"];

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// -------- SQL Query -------
// your logic here will vary

try {
    // ...
    echo 'success';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Content duplication at it's best. If a different question has the same answer, the question is a duplicate, vote so instead of duplicating answers.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but very similar. I can see your point though.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 thanks for your help. I did exactly what you have given in the answer and when I click on the Update it redirect to the new page and open the source code. I hope I have done something wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: I got the error message as Undefined index: rxdtime, Undefined index: txid,Undefined index: balance,Undefined index: ref. That the value has not been passed to the script. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Is the HTML for the link exactly as shown, with the `data-*` attributes? And are you including the jQuery library on your page?

Comment: yes the data-* is correct and I have include the jQuery library also.

Comment: Check your JavaScript console in your browser for any errors. The fact that it is redirecting to a new page indicates that the JavaScript isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<a href>`, use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to pass the values to your php and get the result back-

```
$.post('updateRCstatus/test.html', { 'rxdtime': <?php ecdho $time ?>, OTHER_PARAMS },
  function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```