# Passing variables into a function instead of ahref

Tags: php, function, variables, parameters

Instead of using code like this:

```
'<td><a href="CancelClass.php?MemberId=' . $memberId .'&ClassId=' . $classId .' "> Cancel</a>
```

I would like to be able to simply call a function and pass the $memberId and $classId into that instead of having to create a new PHP page to run some code with these values.

So basically the user will click the 'cancel' button and then it will run a function from another class, instead of clicking the button and then having another page deal with the request.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could do an ajax call to another php page.  That php page would run that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a PHP Script without redirecting or refreshing the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349978/running-a-php-script-without-redirecting-or-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

No! You have to use JavaScript for that. PHP is a [server-side language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), and PHP process died when you see something in the browser page.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for HTML page loaded in a browser and a PHP program hosted on a web server to interact is through HTTP requests.

You can't call a PHP function from a web page. You can only make an HTTP request (e.g. through a link, a form submission or XMLHttpRequest) which sends some data to a PHP program. That program can then look at the data (e.g. via `$_GET`) and use that to determine which function to call.